# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated

Tags: android

I am using Android studio 4.2

```
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$3(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:186)
at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:268)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:184)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkExecutionException: A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$WorkItemExecution.waitForCompletion(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:142)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForItemsAndGatherFailures(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:94)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForAll(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:80)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.waitForCompletion(DefaultAsyncWorkTracker.java:68)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$2.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:502)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:56)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$run$1(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.runWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:45)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:71)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:479)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:462)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$400(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:105)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.executeWithPreviousOutputFiles(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:273)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:251)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$executeOperation$0(ExecuteStep.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.executeOperation(ExecuteStep.java:65)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.access$000(ExecuteStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep$1.call(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:72)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RemovePreviousOutputsStep.execute(RemovePreviousOutputsStep.java:42)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:77)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:58)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:57)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateAfterExecutionStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.executeWithoutCache(BuildCacheStep.java:176)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BuildCacheStep.execute(BuildCacheStep.java:47)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreExecutionStateStep.execute(StoreExecutionStateStep.java:32)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:25)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:102)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:95)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:55)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:39)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:44)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:37)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:27)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:96)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:83)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.execute(CaptureStateBeforeExecutionStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ValidateStep.execute(ValidateStep.java:74)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.lambda$execute$2(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:88)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipEmptyWorkStep.execute(SkipEmptyWorkStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsStartedStep.java:38)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.LoadExecutionStateStep.execute(LoadExecutionStateStep.java:34)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.lambda$execute$0(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution$3.withWorkspace(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:286)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:43)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.AssignWorkspaceStep.execute(AssignWorkspaceStep.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentityCacheStep.execute(IdentityCacheStep.java:30)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.IdentifyStep.execute(IdentifyStep.java:40)
at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultExecutionEngine.execute(DefaultExecutionEngine.java:41)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:183)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeIfValid(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:183)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:173)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:109)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:62)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:77)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:55)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:41)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:411)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:398)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:391)
at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:377)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.lambda$run$0(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:127)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:191)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:182)
at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:124)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution.run(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:232)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction.execute(KaptWithoutKotlincTask.kt:198)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing(annotationProcessing.kt:81)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.AnnotationProcessingKt.doAnnotationProcessing$default(annotationProcessing.kt:31)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.Kapt.kapt(Kapt.kt:45)
... 31 more
Caused by: com.sun.tools.javac.processing.AnnotationProcessingError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:707)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:786)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:881)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1222)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1334)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1258)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/annotation/Generated
at dagger.internal.codegen.SourceFileGenerator.<clinit>(SourceFileGenerator.java:43)
at dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor.initSteps(ComponentProcessor.java:108)
at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.init(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:119)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.incremental.IncrementalProcessor.init(incrementalProcessors.kt:36)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.base.ProcessorWrapper.init(annotationProcessing.kt:175)
at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.<init>(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:686)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.Generated
... 48 more
```

How to solve the issue?

Answer (score -2):

be sure have a good network and try again for build gradle if got error again like that try do it with vpn